# how to call a function on a Perl Smart::Comment?

Tags: perl

Consider the following Perl code:

```
use Smart::Comments;
print "${ \return_hello() }\n";
### ${ \return_hello() }
sub return_hello {return 'hello'}
```

produces the output:

```
hello

### ${ \return_hello() }
```

How could I call the `return_hello` function right on the smart comment to get it to print `hello`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart%3a%3aComments) needs a little help to determine that a subroutine should be called.  Adding a label seems to work:

```
### returns: return_hello()
```

which prints:

```
### returns: 'hello'
```